# How to automatically add a new row to another table PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, row

I have 2 tables that have  one-to-one relationship in mySQL. they both have the same user_id as Primary key, and I need somehow when I insert a post into the my first table, automatically  be able to insert the row with same user_id to my second table. Is there any mysql command or PHP script that I can use it ?

Comment: Sounds like it might be easier just to combine the tables into one if they are related by their primary keys - why are there two tables?

Comment: You could use a trigger for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might set up a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) in the database. These trigger entities are stored in the database's structure, with PHP you might only execute the `CREATE TRIGGER` query which creates one.

However, two tables having the exact same data as their `PRIMARY KEY` sounds like your database structure is a bit badly modelled. You should take time to remodel the database, essentially merging (if possible) the two tables together.

And if you are using PHP to `INSERT INTO` the database, you can call the two queries after each other:

```
INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2...) VALUES (value1, value2...)
INSERT INTO table2(field1, field2...) VALUES (value1, value2...)
```

But reliance on two queries after each other requires pinpoint accuracy as the primary keys might go out of sync, breaking the relations.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right you can get the inserted user_id from the first table and use that to insert a new row in the second table.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM first_table ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Now $row['user_id'] can be inserted in the second table.

This could of course be risky if many rows are inserted at the same time.

Comment: Using `ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1` is inefficient, it orders the entire table then skims the top row off.  Just do `SELECT MAX(id) FROM...`